# facebook login working on development mode or server mod, when create a build, it's not working on any devices. react native app

Tags: react-native

[image]

feature unavailable facebook login in currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additionl details for this app. please try again later

working only on my system and device, not working in others,
how to resolve this issue,please help

```
FacebookSignIn = async () => {
    // Attempt login with permissions
    try {
        const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
        console.log("fb login", result)
        if (!result.isCancelled) {
            await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
                .then(async res => {
                    console.log("token", res);
                    // Create a Firebase credential with the AccessToken
                    const facebookCredential = auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.accessToken);


                    console.log("token", res);
                    // Sign-in the user with the credential
                    this.setState({ loder: true })
                    await auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log("Login Data", response);
                            const data = {
                                "name": response.additionalUserInfo.profile.first_name,
                                "email": response.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
                                "user_type": 0
                            }
                            console.log(data);
                            fetchPostMethod('/facebook-sign-up', data)
                                .then(async response => {
                                    this.setState({ loder: false })
                                    if (response.status == 200) {
                                        if (response.data.user_type == 0) {
                                            try {
                                                let user = JSON.stringify(response?.data?.user_type)
                                                await AsyncStorage.setItem('SignINToken', response?.data?.token);
                                                await AsyncStorage.setItem('UserType', user);
                                                this.logmodl();
                                            } catch (e) {
                                                console.log("Login error", e)
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            this.user();
                                        }

                                        console.log("SignIn Successful", response);
                                    } else {
                                        this.field();
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(response => {
                                    this.setState({ loder: false })
                                    console.log("SignIn faild", response.message);
                                })
                            this.setState({ FacebookUserInfo: response });
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log('Login Data Error', error);
                        })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Something went wrong obtaining access token ', error);
                })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR WHILE LOGIN! ", error);
    }
}
```

feature unavailable facebook login in currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additionl details for this app. please try again later

working only on my system and device, not working in others,
how to resolve this issue,please help

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention! For enable Facebook login for other users you need visit the [Facebook developer site](https://developers.facebook.com)

and enable work mode for application, moving this switch  [image]

[image]